# Getting memory limit error when uploading csv file to db2

Tags: python, database, db2

I am getting " The statement was not processed because a limit such as a memory limit, an SQL limit, or a database limit was reached." when i try to upload a csv file to ibm db2 using python

Here is my code:
result.to_sql(table_name,connection,schema_name,method='multi',index=False,if_exists='replace',chunksize=50)

Comment: How many bytes are in the csv file? (it's size).  Are you on a free Db2-lite plan for IBM Db2 on cloud?

Comment: its around 6 mb

Comment: Can you check the db2diag.log for more details on the error?

Comment: db2 not in linux . it is on db2 cloud credentials

Comment: Are you on a "free"  Db2-lite plan ?   Use the web console to check the current utilization of your resources.